# New Lightning Warning

Tags: lightning

Last night when I left, I was not receiving this warning.  This morning, I get this warning multiple times.  Even if I navigate to something that I have not customized at all (ie the dashboard home tab)

When I click on the error it takes me to various places of my database including the one container and one of my custom components.  When I look at the line in under "aura_proddebug.js" I see the following on the line:

```
console.group(msg); // tslint:disable-line

Here are the warnings:
[LWC warning]: Dangerously Mutating Object [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]. This object was passed to you from a parent component, and should not be mutated here. This will be removed in the near future.
aura_proddebug.js:223 [LWC warning]: Dangerously Mutating Object [object Object]. This object was passed to you from a parent component, and should not be mutated here. This will be removed in the near future.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! thanks!!

Fred

Comment: Is there any custom component?

Comment: I have several components in the system.  Could it be a lighting application event that is causing the problem?  thanks!!!

Comment: I am getting the same issue with the simplest of the component.

Comment: any updates on this issue?

Comment: I have not heard of any updates

Comment: This question is literally the only reference on Google to the exact phrase "Dangerously Mutating Object".